# How to set the GridView or GridLayout to fill the height of the screen and force all the rows to be of equal height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I have a few views that I have to place in a 4 x 6 grid. Each of the views should have the same width w and same height h and fill the screen. What I want is to use GridLayout or GridView to draw these.

I know that I can use the stretchMode = "columnWidth" in GridView which sets equal width to each of its children. I also want it to set equal height and fill the screen vertically.

Can I achieve this by using any of GridView or if not possible then GridLayout? I am looking for GridView before switching to LinearLayouts and using weights because I have custom views as the grid items and I would love to use adapters rather than coding for each element.

Comment: can you post you code as I think making all child till root to grid element fill_parent/parent  should work for you....

Comment: I did not understand what you meant by "making all child root to grid element fill_parent/parent"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a custom layout which extends linear layout. I found that for my case this is a better approach and I had more control over all the touch events on the layout and the children themselves.

Comment: can you past your custom layout here ?i have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `Adapters` with `LinearLayouts` or `TableLayout`, you just have to add the views programatically and call the getView() method yourself.  `GridView` is more meant for a dynamic number of items and handles its own scrolling.

This can be done using something like this in your onCreateView() or whatever:

```
mAdapter = new FooAdapter();
mList = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
for(int i = 0; i< mAdapter.getCount(); i++){
    View child = mAdapter.getView(i, null, mList);
    mList.addView(child);
}
```

If you are possibly just changing the data, passing the old views as convertViews may speed things up.

Comment: Can you explain or show some references on how I can use Adapters with LinearLayouts/TableLayout?

Comment: I know how to use gridviews and listviews in a LinearLayout. I specifically asked that I need a solution for having fixed number of rows in a grid and make thm fill the screen with equal height for each row and still use the adapter. I do not see anything in your solution that does that. Thank you for trying to help though.

Comment: the `layout_weight` attribute will do that for you.  This solution does not involve either GridView or ListView.